# How to load and merge mutliple json files into one dataframe?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have got multiple json files (all of the same format with the same headers) that I would like to load and merge into one dataframe.

```
for f_name in glob('some_dir/*.json'):
     ww = pd.read_json(f_name, lines=True)
```

The above two lines of code load all .json files, each entry in the json file is a string and the variable ww contains multiple dataframes (when printing type(ww)).

Afterwards I have tried to convert each entry into a dictionary using:

```
kk = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(ww))
```

Then tried using pd.concat to combine them all, this is the error message I received when using pd.concat:

```
 TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

It would be great if anyone could explain how to fix this and why printing type gives me a different type to what it actually seem to be.

Edit: 
Each json file has multiple of inputs looking like this:

```
 {"Name":"Anna", "Year": "1987", "Location":"Asia","Colour":"Blue"}
```

Expected Output:

```
 Name Year Location Colour 
 Anna 1987 Asia     Blue
```

Comment: please mention a sample of your input data and expected output as well. Right now, it is too vague to make any assumption.

Comment: @AbdurRehman I have made an example for the input and expected output - thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: show me the data of `ww`.